# ERROR: "/tmp/jl_F8q8cm/Registry.toml": No such file in Julia REPL

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

I am tryin to update the packages in my current environment through the package manager and get the following error:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> update
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
┌ Warning: could not download https://pkg.julialang.org/registry/23338594-aafe-5451-b93e-139f81909106/46715bc8c87dc9f8d86b589ce090af6fcca81565
└ @ Pkg.Types /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Pkg/src/Types.jl:1156
ERROR: "/tmp/jl_F8q8cm/Registry.toml": No such file
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(::String, ::String)
    @ Base ./error.jl:42
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the link to the general registry was broken. All that needs to be done to address this is:

```
] registry rm General

]up
```

which will remove the general registry and then re-add it by default when the `up` command is run.